# Uploading CSV files to S3 directly through Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore, python-django-storages

I am creating a django application which is connected to Amazon S3 to save user upload files. This is done using django-storages.

During the course of the app a CSV file is generated. I am able to save the file locally. But how can I upload the file directly to S3 without saving it locally and save the file S3 URL in the database at the same time?

I have tried using StringIO but that generates a TypeError: Unicode objects must be encoded before hashing

Any suggestions/solutions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Install boto3 first
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                  aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                  aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, )

// ...... Get your file or open file ......
file_name = your_file_here
// ......

s3.upload_file(file_name, AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
               path_where_you_want_to_store))

// Ex: s3.upload_file(file_name, AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
//                           '%s/%s' % ('media/user/file', file_name))
```